# Как получить полные заголовки нескольких писем?

Tags: php, python, email, imap

Задача: получить следующие заголовки писем с почтового ящика Gmail: 
 - Элемент списка
 - Email отправителя
 - Email получателя
 - Тема письма
 - X-EVENT_NAME

Вложения желательно не скачивать.

Всего на ящике порядка 500 000 писем. Желательно иметь возможность фильтрации по вышеупомянутым полям.

Сейчас делаю скрипт на PHP с использованием функций IMAP.

Проблема в том, что imap_fetch_overview() получает все заголовки писем с указанным uid, но только стандартные. 
А мне, помимо стандартных заголовков (отправитель, получатель, дата, тема) нужен еще и заголовок X-EVENT_NAME.

Сейчас ищу uid нужных сообщений при помощи imap_search() и потом получаю заголовки каждого сообщения при помощи imap_header(). Что, естественно, работает очень медленно, а для 500 000 сообщений будет отрабатывать примерно полтора суток.

imap_headers() тоже не подходит, т. к. выдает по строке на каждое письмо, в которых от заголовков остается только то, что помещается (а помещается немного).

Также рассматривал скачивание почты в формате mbox, но подготовка архива занимает тоже большое время, кроме того есть ограничения на количество запросов (1 раз в день, 7 раз в неделю).

Подошло бы любое решение, которое работало бы быстро и получало нужные заголовки. Можно даже полностью скачать все письма с телом, можно даже без фильтрации - лишь бы это не занимало столько времени.

Можно даже на другом языке программирования (к примеру, может в Python есть необходимое?).

Или протокол IMAP по определению не позволяет решить такую задачу за приемлемое время?

Comment: `imap_fetchheader` не подходит? Я думаю, решение есть. Это поток. Реализация `imap_fetch_overview` запрашивает стандартные заголовки, поэтому `X-EVENT_NAME` не попадает. По спеке, можно попробовать что-то типа `HEADER.FIELDS (X-EVENT_NAME FROM TO SUBJECT)`. Но как это сделать на PHP - нет идей. На NodeJS вот есть пакетик https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap

Comment: Не подходит, в том-то и деле. 
Попробовал подключиться по telnet. Получить заголовки 2743 писем заняло чуть больше 7 секунд. Команда простейшая: «. fetch 501:506 (body[header.fields (from to subject date X-EVENT_NAME)]» Вместо диапазона (501:506) можно перечислять через запятую или указать только одно письмо. 
Единственное - парсить ответ будет немного посложнее.
Странно что на php такой базовый функционал недоступен. Попробую еще на питоне.

Comment: Попробовал через `proc_open` + `openssl` на PHP. Работает, но замучаешься обрабатывать поток, поэтому забросил на этапе авторизации. Поставил пакет на nodeJS, [что упоминул выше](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap), просто копи-паста с примера документации. Easy. 800 писем за 7 секунд. Время зависит от количества не линейно. Для 100 заняло 4 секунды. Для 10 - 3 секунды. Если нужно прикрутить к пыху, то через `shell_exec`, например. Ну придется еще nodejs ставить, но это не сложно.